# Infopath validation rules for greater than or less than dont work properly

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

I have a very strange issue with Infopath. 
I have create a list in a temp sharepoint sub-site and configured several rules. Everything was working properly. I tried to move this list to a new sharepoint site and tried to configure the same rules. For some strange reason the when I configure a rule for a field to be less or equal of another field works the opposite.

For example **ColumnA has value 1000$** and on **ColumnB the user has to set an amount <= to ColumnA**. So I configure rule in **ColumnB to be "less or equal" to ColumnA**. 
 When I test the list and I enter 999 or 1000 I get the error I was supposed to get if I enter a value greater than 1000. 
Also the 1000 is not working. Even if I accept this strange issue and set the opposite rule the "equal to" does not work even if I add a 2nd rule for the equal.

*Any idea? thanks in advance for your help*

Comment: can you attach screenshots and which error you've got?

Answer (score 0):

What’s the column type for ColumnA and ColumnB? Make sure the column type for these two column are the same.

And in InfoPath form, create rule for columnB with condition as “ColumnB is greater than columnA:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Both are currency fields. I apply the validation rule on the field that the user will need to update. I preset amounts in Column A and I ask the user to enter an amount in Column B that should be less or equal to Column A. So the rule I put is: **Column B is less than or equal to Column A**

Comment: In the rule, if the column value you enter matches condition, the screen tip will display. if we want user to get error when enter columnB > column A, we need to type the rule as "is greater than". whether the issue exists when you use "is greater than"?

Comment: thanks a lot. I have reverted and it is working. thanks again

Comment: I'm glad to help you. You can mark this post as answer if it helps. Thanks for your understanding.